# Double Escaping Escapes - Working with Bytes

Tags: vb.net

I've got the need to escape any possible ascii escapes in a file.  I've written this, and thought it was working well but just noticed that for some reason, there is a bunch of extra bytes at the end of the file now.  There is probably a better way to do this, so here I am :)  What's the best way to find bytes, and add a byte next to it?

```
Dim imageData() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(f_imagePath)
'Escape any ascii escapes
For i As Int32 = 0 To imageData.Length
    If imageData(i) = &H1B Then
        ReDim Preserve imageData(imageData.Length + 1)
        'shift entire array
        Dim arrCopy(imageData.Length + 1) As Byte
        Array.Copy(imageData, 0, arrCopy, 0, i)
        arrCopy(i) = &H1B
        Array.Copy(imageData, i, arrCopy, i + 1, imageData.Length - i)
        imageData = arrCopy
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list...

```
    Dim imageData() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(f_imagePath)
    Dim newIMGData As New List(Of Byte)
    'Escape any ascii escapes
    For i As Int32 = 0 To imageData.Length
        If imageData(i) = &H1B Then
            'not sure about this,
            newIMGData.Add(imageData(i)) 'add the &H1B
            newIMGData.Add(&H0) 'add the other character
        Else
            newIMGData.Add(imageData(i))
        End If
    Next
    imageData = newIMGData.ToArray
```